# Where does this formula for effective thickness of air come from?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I have a formula for effective thickness of air for alpha particles, i.e.

$$d(p,T)=\left[\frac{273.15 K}{T}\cdot\frac{p}{100 kPa}\right]\cdot 16 mm$$

where $p$, $T$ are absolute values of pressure and temperature, 16 mm are the layers of air.

Where does this formula come from? Here is the source of this formula: [formula](https://postimg.cc/vxhKmf4R)

Comment: (OK, where is the alpha particle energy in there?) But, stopping the alpha is a function of the number of particles it has to hit to give up the energy. In air, which is nearly an ideal gas, the density depends on T and p. The 16mm is the normalization for a given alpha energy based on experimental values and/or stopping energy calculations.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the source of that formula, and for that matter you might check to see if the adjacent text discusses how it's applicable.

Comment: Your link is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be the thickness compared to "normal condition? at 0°C and atmospheric pressure of 100kPa. The density of air changes proportional to pressure and inverse to temperature.